# Help solving first order differential equation with IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Trying to solve this as an explicit function of x...

$x\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y$

$y(1) = 0$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{y}{x}$

I substituted $u=\frac{y}{x} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$

Which when substituted into the initial equation gives:

$u + x\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x} + u$

$ \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{1}{x^2}$

Integrate and sub u out:

$\frac{y}{x} = -\frac{1}{x} + C$

$y=-1+C$

But this is wrong, im not sure why... thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{y}{x}=-\frac{1}{x}+C $$
$$ y=-1+Cx $$

Answer (score 0):

$$x\frac{dy}{dx}=1+y$$
It's separable:
$$\dfrac{dy}{y+1}=\dfrac {dx}x$$
$$\ln |{y+1}|=\ln |x|+C$$
$$y+1=cx$$
$$\implies y(x)=cx-1$$